# UFW does not block any ports (Ubuntu 22.04)

Tags: firewalls, ubuntu

On my fresh Hetzner Cloud server, the ufw seems to be ineffective. The status output is the following:

```
Status: active

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
OpenSSH                    ALLOW       Anywhere
80                         ALLOW       Anywhere
443                        ALLOW       Anywhere
OpenSSH (v6)               ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
80 (v6)                    ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
443 (v6)                   ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
```

Despite ufw being active on this fresh install, all ports are accessible (I removed the IP from the screenshot):

[image]

Is a reboot required after activating ufw or an ufw rule?